# regex to match between two charcters

Tags: regex

i want to extract

```
t=1567771745953
```

from

```
t=1567771745953&amp
```

I tried this regex but it did not work

```
t=[^]&
```

Comment: Use `\bt=[^&]+`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only portion of text you'd like to extract, and your string won't change, you can use `(t=\d+)&amp`

This will capture `t=` and then one or more digits, up to the `&amp` (which will be matched, but not captured).

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/bcEiDt/1)

If, instead, you would like to capture *only* whatever text is between `t=` and `&`, but that text isn't restricted to digits, you can use `t=(.*?)&` instead.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/bcEiDt/2/)